# How do I fix - File Contains Invalid Character - error with Tresorit

Tags: macos, windows-10

I am getting several hundred files giving error "File Contains Invalid Character" when syncing with Tresorit.

Their support page instructs to change the file names manually which would take hours.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I found a great software tool for Mac OSX that can bulk edit files and remove the illegal characters automatically for you:

http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/index.html

(I am not affiliated with the software company, just found it useful!)